# Getting a work visa at the border of Canada over the Weekend

Tags: canada, borders, working-visas

I have a job in Canada and based on how the paperwork is going, I will need to get a work visa as I cross the border (US citizen taking a temporary position in Canada, so this is okay under current Covid restrictions).

With the way my schedule is working out, it looks like I will only be able to cross over on a Saturday. Can I still apply for a work visa at the border on a Saturday, or do I need to figure out a way to arrange for me to get there on a weekday?

Comment: I would start by checking the current opening hours of the port of entry you have in mind [here](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/do-rb/openpoe-temp-pdeouvert/air-aerien-eng.html). Most POEs seem to be open 7 days a week but some are not, and hours vary quite a bit. Then I would probably contact the specific POE to ask.

Comment: Thank you, once I finally found the correct phone number (the one I had called before realizing I might be able to find an answer online had me jumping through 8 million option menus) thanks to your recommendation to call a specific POE, I was able to determine that it doesn’t matter if I cross during the week or over the weekend, as long as as it is open.

Comment: you may want to post this as an answer for future readers having the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @jcaron, I was able to figure out what I needed to do and got in touch with an agent at a POE.  I was told that it doesn’t matter which POE you come in or when, as long as the border crossing is open, you can get the visa.

P.S. I was told by someone else it’s best to cross into the province where you need the work visa, e.g., if you are working in Ontario, cross the border into Ontario. Not sure if it’s still possible to do it crossing into another province; my guess is it probably is, but that is pure speculation.

Comment: +1 Welcome to Canada.